# How to connect Django project to containerized PostgreSQL database?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, django-postgresql

I'm trying to connect my local django project to a Postgres DB container. I am not sure why I get this error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection failed: :1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "demo" does not exist". Could you please help me figure out where I went wrong?

Here is my .env file:

```
POSTGRES_USER=demo
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=demo
POSTGRES_NAME=demo
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
  postgres_data:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

And here is the databases section of my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": env('POSTGRES_NAME'),
        "USER": env('POSTGRES_USER'),
        "PASSWORD": env('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        "HOST": "localhost",  # set in docker-compose.yml
        "PORT": 5432,  # default postgres port
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run a local PostgreSQL server on your host machine by the past ? Not using a Docker container, directly on your machine.

Comment: @ABWassim Yes I think so

Comment: Are you on a Linux OS ? If so execute `lsof -i:5432 | grep -i 'LISTEN'` and try to see if something is running on port 5432 of your machine.

Comment: @ABWassim MacOS but yes I ran the command (without starting the container) and I see two postgres related things. Both have the same PID (not sure what that is) and one is using IPv6 and the other is using IPv4. What do I do about these? Should I just send the docker database to different port? Not sure if that's bad practice.

Comment: So you have an ongoing running PostgreSQL service on port 5432 on your local machine that's conflicting with the Docker database you're also trying to run on 5432. Can you shut it down using `brew services stop postgresql` ? Then make sure the services is not in `LISTEN` state anymore using `lsof -i:5432`, and launch your docker-compose again. If it works then I'll post this as answer :). Answering your question, that's not a bad practice, you could map your PostgreSQL database to any local port you want, so changing the port could also fix the issue while letting you running the local db.

Comment: @ABWassim Ok so a couple things. 1. I tried `brew services stop postgresql` but the services still seem to be in the `LISTEN` state. 2. I tried mapping to port 8080 (changed both the yml and settings.py) where I checked there were no other services running, but when trying to run `python manage.py runserver` I get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection failed: :1), port 8080 failed: FATAL:  role "demo" does not exist`

Comment: Very weird, I managed to run your docker-compose succesfully on my computer and then connecting succesfully with the `psql` CLI with the `demo` user. Can you running `docker-compose down`, delete the volume and `docker-compose up` again ?

Comment: Can you also try to connect to the database using your local CLI ? `psql -h localhost -p 8080 -U demo` ?

Comment: My guess is that your application doesn't read your `settings.py` and still tries to connect to your local database, with the help of default settings maybe.

Comment: @ABWassim Solved it. It ended up being just a matter of deleting the volume. Of course, it was also a problem to have the db container on the same port as my local postgres db so changing it to a different, unused port worked. Thanks for your help, feel free to post the answer!

Comment: Nice :) Ok thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have an already running service on port `5432`, like an old local PostgreSQL instance (use `lsof -i:5432`). If not, try deleting the `postgres_data` of your PostgreSQL Docker database and start it again.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the issue is related to the PostgreSQL user and password not being properly set during the container initialization.

```
environment:
  - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_NAME}
  - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```